# Heading mode Rotating Map

Tags: android, skmaps

I'm using SKMaps v3.0 SDK for Android and I try to change the user Heading mode into Rotating_Map in order to let the user able to rotate map with heading position.

Here is my code :

```
    private void followTheUserWithHeading(int transitionTime){
    mapView.getMapSettings().setCurrentPositionShown(true);
    mapView.getMapSettings().setFollowPositions(true);
    mapView.getMapSettings().setHeadingMode(SKMapSettings.SKHeadingMode.ROTATING_MAP);
    mapView.animateToBearing(1.0f,true,transitionTime);
    mapView.centerOnCurrentPosition(17,true,500);
}
```

With followTheUserWithHeading() being called in onRouteCalculationCompleted method.

Unfortunately, the map does not rotate with mobile phone orientation.

N.B. : the user cone is visible, which is not the case when using SKHeadingMode.ROUTE. So it seems my code is not completely crap ... I also tried ROTATING_HEADING but not better.

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally found a solution to my problem ...

This was not a matter of pedestrian mode. In order to make the ROTATIN_MAP works, you have to implement all sensor event.

See in Android demo project for further details, but here is look to code snippet

```
 private void setHeading(boolean enabled) {
    if (enabled) {
        headingOn = true;
        mapView.getMapSettings().setHeadingMode(SKHeadingMode.ROTATING_MAP);
        startOrientationSensor();
    } else {
        headingOn = false;
        mapView.getMapSettings().setHeadingMode(SKMapSettings.SKHeadingMode.NONE);
        stopOrientationSensor();
    }
}

/**
 * Activates the orientation sensor
 */
private void startOrientationSensor() {
    orientationValues = new float[3];
    SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    Sensor orientationSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, orientationSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}

/**
 * Deactivates the orientation sensor
 */
private void stopOrientationSensor() {
    orientationValues = null;
    SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
```

Comment: I have provided to you the skmaps library related answer. if you want to rotate the map using the heading info it is obvious you need to have access to that heading info, and that is aquired using sensors.

Answer (score 3):

This feature works only when the pedestrian navigation mode is used (set it by using a call like navigationSettings.setNavigationMode(SKNavigationSettings.SKNavigationMode.PEDESTRIAN);)
In order to enable the feature you need to make sure that you call mapView.getMapSettings().setHeadingMode(SKMapSettings.SKHeadingMode.ROTATING_MAP);
just after the navigation is started (navigationManager.startNavigation(navigationSettings);)
I have attached a video below showing the working functionality:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/onnsbeavldxvdpu/20161221_PedestrianNavigation_RotatingMap.mp4?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

This feature is available only in Pedestrian Navigation.

Comment: Okay I didn't mention it but I'm using Pedestrian Navigation mode with Pedestrian Route mode :)